# Azure-machine-learning: Compiling R-script, but different results

Tags: r, machine-learning, azure-machine-learning-service

I've built a ML model in Azure and most of my data transformation / feature generation steps have been carried out in R. 
At first, I transformed the data in R itself (works faster) and uploaded the created csv to ML studio.

Now that my model is finished I tried to run the R-code in ML studio itself, instead of manually uploading a transformed dataset. It runs flawlessly. However, when I compare the resulting datasets (the one uploaded and the one created) they differ. The columns have different means, formats and the model performs less. The actual data entries/cells look fine.

I feel it has to do with the format of the columns so I tried stuff like converted the columns to character type, or converting the resulting dataset to csv (in ML studio) and letting ML studio figure out how to format them.

So far, no results.

Has anyone already faced this problem? What is the solution?

Answer (score 2):

**Managed to solve it:**

- The manually uploaded dataset was formatted in Azure with "String features" only. (Because there where some NA's studio ML formats them this way).
- The R script however, formats the NA's differently and thus the columns as well.

I'm not entirely sure what caused the different results because the data was character-wise identical. Only the NA's where formatted differently, as where the columns.

The following solved my problem (at the end of the Rscript in studio ML):

```
data = data.frame(lapply(data, as.character), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
data[is.na(data)] = "NA"
```

Comment: Are NA's equivalent to NULLs or missing values?